# GridView Paging doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an old web forms project on support. And I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with paging. I have this code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" 
    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging ="true" PageSize="20"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="products_id" CssClass="gridview" OnRowCommand="gvProducts_RowCommand"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvProducts_SelectedIndexChanging"   
    OnRowDataBound="gvProducts_RowDataBound" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvProducts_PageIndexChanging"
    DataSourceID="dsSearchResult" >
    <PagerTemplate>
        <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
    </PagerTemplate>
```

This is data sourse:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsSearchResult" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetFindedProducts"
EnableViewState ="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
EnablePaging="True" TypeName="Paging.ResultSearch" 
SortParameterName="sortExpression">
```

And this is page index changing method:

```
protected void gvProducts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvProducts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}
```

When I click on paging buttons nothing happends (just numbers of pages changes). I've tryed to find solution, but all resolves doesn't work. 
And this is my SelectMethod:

```
public List<BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult_ext> GetFindedProducts(int maximumRows, int startPageIndex, int startRowIndex, string sortExpression, string model, string param)
    {            
        SphinxClient client = new SphinxClient();
        string idProducts = client.GetIdProducts(model);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Globals.ConnectionString);
        string cmdText = "SearchProducts";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // it's a default value
        command.CommandTimeout = 100;
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.Add("@id_array", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idProducts;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        try
        {               
            connection.Open();         
            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close(); 
            throw new Exception("Can't get the list of products/GetProductsDataSet!", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return TopagedResult_ext(ds);
    }

 public List<BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult_ext> TopagedResult_ext(DataSet q)
    {
        DataRowCollection dr = q.Tables[0].Rows;
        List<BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult_ext> searchResultArr = new List<BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult_ext>();
        DataRow r;
        //BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult searchResult;
        BOM.SearchProducts_pagedResult_ext searchResult_ext;
        for (int i=0; i < dr.Count; i++)
        {
            r = dr[i];
            searchResult_ext = fillData(r);
            searchResultArr.Add(searchResult_ext);
        }
        return searchResultArr;
    }
```

May anyone help me?

Comment: it seems code is corret....

Comment: You need to have SelectCountMethod in ObjectDataSource.

Comment: http://developer.webnodes.com/paging-in-a-gridview-using-an-objectdatasource

Comment: I have such method. I've edited post. Now you may find it.

Comment: Thanks, I really miss Count(( Thanks for help.